# Why is $M_{21}\cong PSL_3(\mathbb{F}_4)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

I have recently been reading about the Large Mathieu Groups in "The Finite Simple Groups" by Robert Wilson and I have not come across any explanation of this isomorphism as of yet. In this context, $M_{21}$ is described as the point stabiliser of $M_{22}$, which is described as the point stabiliser of $M_{23}$, and so on.

Comment: $M_{24}$ is not isomorphic to $PSL(3,4)$. It can be "built from" $PSL(3,4)$, see the wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_group_M24#M24_from_PSL.283.2C4.29

Comment: He probably meant to ask why is $M_{21} \cong {\rm PSL}_3(4)$. The answer will depend on how you define $M_{24}$. If you construct it from ${\rm PSL}_3(4)$ then it's clear!

Comment: Apologies, I incorrectly typed $M_{24}$ instead of $M_{21}$. The construction I worked through of $M_{24}$ uses the Extended Binary Golay Code and Witt design as in Wilson's book. Then defines $M_{23}$, $M_{22}$ and $M_{21}$ recursively as point stabilisers.

Comment: Here is quick explanation without proofs. $M_{24}$ is the automorphism group of a Steiner System $S(5,8,24)$. Hence the $3$-point stabilizer is contained in the automorphism group of a Steiner system $S(2,5,21)$. But that's a projective plane of order $4$, and there is a unique such plane. It's automorphism group is the group $P\Gamma L(3,4)$, which has $PSL(3,4)$ as subgroup of index $6$. In fact $P\Gamma L(3,4)$ is the setwise stabilizer of $3$ points in $M_{24}$.

Comment: This helped a great deal. Thanks very much.